# How to build a component with own data in interia with vue3?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I want to build a re-usable component that shows the count of all users and has a filter to reload data. It's an easy task, when I would pass the data from the parent component down as a prop. But I want it to be fully standalone (if this is a good practice and has no cons) component, with his "own" data.

I made the parent view:

```js
<script setup>
import MyView from '@/Pages/MyView.vue'
</script>
<template>
    <MyView />
</template>
```

and the view:

```js
<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue'
import {router} from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const count = ref(0)

const getData = (year) => {
    router.get(
        route('view-data'),
        {date: `${year}-01-01`},
        {
            preserveState: true,
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                count.value = data.props.count
            },
            onError: (error) => {
                console.log({error})
            },
        }
    )
}

onMounted(() => {
    getData(2022)
})
</script>

<template>
    {{count}}<br>
    <button @click="getData(2023)">2023</button>
</template>
```

the route:

```php
Router::get('view-data', ViewDataController::class)->name('view-data');
```

and the controller:

```php
class ViewDataController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return inertia()->render('MyView', [
            'count' => (int) User::whereDate('created_at', '>', $request->input('date'))->count(),
        ]);
        /* return response()->json([
            'count' => (int) User::whereDate('created_at', '>', $request->input('date'))->count(),
        ]);*/
    }
}
```

Where have issues with:

- I tried the json response, what is the most logical approach for me, but this just renders an iframe with the count. I think, because this is not the way, inertia visits works
- I would implement an api route and use i typical axios.get request, but I'm currently fighting back because I read once *"with Inertia, you don't need the api routes"*
- The current approach with the inertia page response is technically working, but it renders the entire component as a full page component instead of as a component implemented in a parent

So what's the correct way of building such a component? Or would you better recommend me, to pass the data to the parent and as a prop to the `MyView` (what I just personally don't like as it feels dirty)

Answer (score 0):

Use axios instead of inertia router, I also used it in many projects and before using this I search for it and found axios the solution.

```
axios.get(route('view-data', {date: '2023-01-01'})).then(res => {
    // do what ever you want
}).catch(err => {
    // catch error
})
```